# USA and Canada with jvectormap

Tags: converters, jvectormap

I'm looking for a map of (US + Canada) together with states/provinces respectively.

This's what I've done so far:

- Downloaded jVectorMap 1.2.2 from [here](http://jvectormap.com/download/);
- After reading [this](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/gis-converter/), installed GDAL and Shapely;
- Downloaded `10m Admin 1` package from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/);

Than, according to [this](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/issues/170) thread, it is possible to do what I need using following:

```
python converter.py --width 900 --country_name_index 12 --country_code_index 18 --longitude0 -100 --where="iso_a2 = 'CA' OR iso_a2 = 'US'" --projection lcc --name us_ca ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.shp ../jquery-jvectormap-us-ca-lcc-en.js
```

where `--country_name_index 12 --country_code_index 18` part doesn't make any sense to me, since I'm trying to convert 2 countries.

Anyways, after running suggested code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converter.py", line 296, in <module>
    converter.convert(args['output_file'])
  File "converter.py", line 144, in convert
    self.loadData()
  File "converter.py", line 89, in loadData
    self.loadDataSource( sourceConfig )
  File "converter.py", line 130, in loadDataSource
    shapelyGeometry = shapely.wkb.loads( geometry.ExportToWkb() )
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wkb'
```

I find this really odd, unless I missed something in installation. 
After adding `import shapely.wkb` to `converter.py` I get `Alaska` with name `State` and `Yukon` as `Territory`, and that's it.

What am I missing here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: looking for the same map did you ever succeed? Would be nice to put on github

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. Solved it by using the shapefile, **10m_cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.shp** from the package [naturalearth all vector themes.](http://www.nacis.org/naturalearth/packages/natural_earth_vector.zip) 
But only downside is that the output JS file is too big. It comes up to 2MB easily. I'll try using shapefile from different source next time and let you know. But for now at least this works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when building continent maps. The fix was to use an older convert.py version (1.1.1 rather than 1.2.2). You still need to input --country_name_index and --country_code_index flag so give whatever you want as values. The map produced is fine.
convert.py 1.1.1 can be found here :
https://github.com/jfhovinne/jvectormap-maps-builder